# MTM relationship in Ruby-on-Rails 4 and PostgreSQL using GUIDs as ID's

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, many-to-many

new to Rails and using Ruby On Rails 4.0.3 with Ruby 2.2.0 with PostgreSQL, I'm attempting to have this database sctructure using GUID's as Id's.

My Goal: I want to have many phone numbers belong to many people as an example.

So i [built a little test app which can be found here](https://bitbucket.org/itomek/ruby-test-project) and basically [followed the Association guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association) to create a Many-to-Many table.

So here is my model with comments added for clarity:

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to  :contact
end

class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many    :addresses
    has_many    :phoneNumbers
end

class PhoneNumber < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many    :contacts
end
```

Here is the migration setup:

```
class CreateAddresses < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :addresses, id: :uuid do |t|
      #t.belongs_to :contacts
      t.text                :street1
      t.text                :city

      t.timestamps
    end

    add_column  :addresses, :contact_id,    :uuid
  end
end

class CreateContacts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :contacts, id: :uuid do |t|
      t.text :firstName
      t.text :lastName

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreatePhoneNumbers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :phone_numbers, id: :uuid do |t|
      t.text :number
      t.text :name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

# the MTM
class CreateContactsPhoneNumbers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table    :contacts_phone_numbers, id:  :uuid

    add_column  :contacts_phone_numbers,    :contact_id,    :uuid
    add_column  :contacts_phone_numbers,    :phone_number_id,   :uuid
  end
end
```

The SQL is output as such:

```
CREATE TABLE addresses (
    id uuid DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4() NOT NULL,
    street1 text,
    city text,
    created_at timestamp without time zone,
    updated_at timestamp without time zone,
    contact_id uuid
);

CREATE TABLE contacts (
    id uuid DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4() NOT NULL,
    "firstName" text,
    "lastName" text,
    created_at timestamp without time zone,
    updated_at timestamp without time zone
);

CREATE TABLE phone_numbers (
    id uuid DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4() NOT NULL,
    number text,
    name text,
    created_at timestamp without time zone,
    updated_at timestamp without time zone
);

CREATE TABLE contacts_phone_numbers (
    id uuid DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4() NOT NULL,
    contact_id uuid,
    phone_number_id uuid
);
```

and here is a part of my example seed script

```
varC = Contact.create(firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe")
varA = Address.create(street1: "10 Somewhere Pl", city: "Ogurek", contact: varC)
```

Note here that you can succesfully get the contact when querying like so after jsut this migration

```
puts Address.first.contact.firstname
# John
```

however, once I chagne the seed script to this:

```
varC = Contact.create(firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe")
varA = Address.create(street1: "10 Somewhere Pl", city: "Ogurek", contact: varC)

varP = PhoneNumber.create(number: "2342342345", name: "home")
varC.phoneNumbers = varP
varC.save

varP.contacts = varC
varP.save
```

and I run rake db:migrate, I'll get the following output (note the error):

```
==  EnablePostgresUuid: migrating =============================================
-- execute("create extension \"uuid-ossp\"")
   -> 0.0018s
==  EnablePostgresUuid: migrated (0.0024s) ====================================

==  CreateAddresses: migrating ================================================
-- create_table(:addresses, {:id=>:uuid})
   -> 0.0036s
-- add_column(:addresses, :contact_id, :uuid)
   -> 0.0005s
==  CreateAddresses: migrated (0.0053s) =======================================

==  CreateContacts: migrating =================================================
-- create_table(:contacts, {:id=>:uuid})
   -> 0.0024s
==  CreateContacts: migrated (0.0031s) ========================================

==  CreatePhoneNumbers: migrating =============================================
-- create_table(:phone_numbers, {:id=>:uuid})
   -> 0.0023s
==  CreatePhoneNumbers: migrated (0.0029s) ====================================

==  CreateContactsPhoneNumbers: migrating =====================================
-- create_table(:contacts_phone_numbers, {:id=>:uuid})
   -> 0.0014s
-- add_column(:contacts_phone_numbers, :contact_id, :uuid)
   -> 0.0004s
-- add_column(:contacts_phone_numbers, :phone_number_id, :uuid)
   -> 0.0003s
==  CreateContactsPhoneNumbers: migrated (0.0038s) ============================

** Invoke db:seed (first_time)
** Execute db:seed
** Invoke db:abort_if_pending_migrations (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:abort_if_pending_migrations
rake aborted!
undefined method `each' for #<PhoneNumber:0xa532460>
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@rails4/gems/activemodel-4.0.3/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:439:in `method_missing'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:155:in `method_missing'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:333:in `replace'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:42:in `writer'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:78:in `phoneNumbers='
/_apps/test_site/rails_test1/rtest1/db/seeds.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@rails4/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@rails4/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@rails4/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@rails4/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@rails4/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:540:in `load_seed'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:154:in `load_seed'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:181:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@rails4/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `call'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@rails4/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `block in execute'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@rails4/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `each'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@rails4/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `execute'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@rails4/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:175:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@rails4/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@rails4/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:161:in `invoke'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@rails4/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:149:in `invoke_task'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@rails4/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@rails4/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@rails4/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@rails4/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@rails4/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@rails4/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@rails4/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@rails4/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@rails4/gems/rake-10.1.1/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@rails4/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@rails4/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:seed
```

**Thus my Question**: How can I add a queryable model(s) that can have a MTM relationship using ActiveRecord and how do I save and query it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I finally figured it out, here it is in all of its glory:

First, I had to change to using a has_and_belongs_to_many association instead of a has_many :through like I was trying to (although I'm sure I could get the has_many :through figured out somehow as well), yet as I understand the guide, since I don't care about the join table, I can just use the has_and_belongs_to_many association. Yet, our problem is that we're using GUID's and not Integers.

So I missed something in the [Associations guid](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many), there is one line and its in parentheses:

(though you'll need to remember to create the joining table in the database)

So I changed my model to this:

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many            :addresses
    has_and_belongs_to_many :phoneNumbers
end

class PhoneNumber < ActiveRecord::Base
has_and_belongs_to_many :contacts
end
```

and migration:

```
class CreateContacts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :contacts, id: :uuid do |t|
      t.text :firstName
      t.text :lastName

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreatePhoneNumbers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :phone_numbers, id: :uuid do |t|
      t.text :number
      t.text :name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I then added this migration:

```
class CreateContactsPhoneNumbers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table    :contacts_phone_numbers, id:  :uuid do |t|
      t.uuid :contact_id
      t.uuid :phone_number_id
    end
  end
end
```

all of the above churned out the following SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE contacts (
    id uuid DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4() NOT NULL,
    "firstName" text,
    "lastName" text,
    created_at timestamp without time zone,
    updated_at timestamp without time zone
);

CREATE TABLE phone_numbers (
    id uuid DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4() NOT NULL,
    number text,
    name text,
    created_at timestamp without time zone,
    updated_at timestamp without time zone
);

CREATE TABLE contacts_phone_numbers (
    id uuid DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4() NOT NULL,
    contact_id uuid,
    phone_number_id uuid
);
```

and I can add models like such taken from my seeds.rb:

```
c = Contact.create(firstName: "John", lastName: "Smith")
p = PhoneNumber.create(number: "2342342345", name: "home", contacts: [c])
```

I put the final solution up on the [BitBucket test project](https://bitbucket.org/itomek/ruby-test-project), please see [Commit 762a546](https://bitbucket.org/itomek/ruby-test-project/commits/762a54636ae5e67044984602c5b30b604947d641).

**So, if anyone has any pointers to how I can fix this to be more in line with how the real Rubyists do it, I would love to here it in the comments. Thanks.**